# How to read a file from the x line in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, file, arrays

I read a file from the file system and FTP it to an FTP server. I now have a request to skip the first line (it's a CSV with header info). I think I can somehow do this with the Offset of the stream.Read method (or the write method) but I am not sure how to translate the byte array offset from a single line.

How would I calculate the offset to tell it to only read from the 2nd line of the file?

Thanks

```
// Read the file to be uploaded into a byte array
        stream = File.OpenRead(currentQueuePathAndFileName);
        var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        stream.Close();

        // Get the stream for the request and write the byte array to it
        var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        reqStream.Close();
        return request;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s2tte0y1.aspx). It returns array of strings. Then just `strArray.Skip(1)` will return you all lines except of first.

**UPDATE**

Here is the code:

```
var stringArray = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
if (stringArray.Length > 1)
{
   stringArray = stringArray.Skip(1).ToArray();
   var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
   reqStream.Write(stringArray, 0, stringArray.Length);
   reqStream.Close();       
}
```

Comment: +1 for a KISS solution. It would be even more awesome if we had a File.ReadAllLinesLazy()

Comment: Thanks - but how do I turn that into a buffer? I need to write the buffer to the FTP server (reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);)

Comment: Also, when I tried the .Skip(1) LINQ method it returns no records : var lines1 = lines.Skip(1);   (lines is a string[] with 32 entries (lines) but lines1 has a count of 0?

Comment: Ok, I am new to LINQ. I figured it out what you meant: however, I still then have to read it and turn it into a buffer with a stream - how can I do these in one go?                    var newLines = from x in lines
                                     .Skip<string>(1)
                                 select x;
                    
                    File.WriteAllLines(currentQueuePathAndFileName, newLines.ToArray());

Comment: Thanks Eugene, that's very concise! I am using this, and then I still have to read it into a buffered stream as per my original code (so I am reading the file twice. Is there anyway you could blend your file reading method and output a stream buffer (e.g. like the answer below) so I don't have to parse the file twice?)

Comment: You may pass that `stringArray` directly to the `reqStream.Write(stringArray, 0, stringArray.Length);` operation, don't you? You don't need to read the file twice. See another update.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks Eugene. That code does not compile though - reqStream.Write requires a ByteArray, not a String array, so I used this:                 byte[] byteArrayOfLines = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Join(String.Empty, lines));
                reqStream.Write(byteArrayOfLines, 0, byteArrayOfLines.Length);

Comment: aargh, the String.Join erases all my EOL markers so it all writes on one line. How can I turn my string array into a byte array? Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You should use `string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, lines)`

Comment: I thought of that, I was just concerned that I might alter the layout of the file after I wrote it! Thanks for all your help..

Answer (score 1):

If you need just skip the one line, you can use the reader class, read line, get the current position and read contents as usual.

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("currentQueuePathAndFileName"))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    reader.ReadLine();
    Console.Write(stream.Position);
    var buffer = new byte[stream.Length - stream.Position];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    reqStream.Close();
    return request;
}
```

And Why are you using `RequestStream`? Aren't you supposed to use the `HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream` ?

Comment: This seems to be what I am after, thanks. However, after the reader.Readline() the Stream.Position is written as the end of the file (I made a test file .csv with a few lines and it always advances to EOF after reader.ReadLine(), which means the resulting file is blank).

Comment: WRT to why it is RequestStream - I don't actually know - I found this code somewhere for FTPing a file to an FTP server and it works.

Comment: Could it be that it would work on a text file with a LineEnd but it does not work on a CSV file as Excel treats the new line differently?

Comment: On my system this works, but maybe it's really needs development

Answer (score 0):

You could take the string from your stream input, parse it into lines with array split, and then drop the first, and put it back together, OR, you could regex out the first line, or just look for a line feed and copy the string from there on. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `[StreamReader][1]` class. Then by using ReadLine until the result is null you read all the lines one by one. Just skeep the first one as your requirement. Reading all the file in memory is usually not a good idea ( it does not scale as the file became bigger )

Answer (score 0):

The **brute force approach** to is to iterate through the source byte array and **look for the first occurrence of the carriage return character followed by a line feed (CR+LF)**. That way you'll know the offset in the source array to exclude the first line in the CSV file.

Here's an example:

```
const byte carriageReturn = 13;
const byte lineFeed = 10;
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(currentQueuePathAndFileName);
int offset = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
{
    if (file[i] == carriageReturn && file[++i] == lineFeed)
    {
        offset = i + 2;
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that this example assumes **the source CSV file was created on Windows**, since [line breaks are expressed differently on other platforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations).

**Related resources:**

- [Environment.NewLine Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)